# Which way is better for handling exception from the sub-project (provider)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, design-patterns

I have a microservice. It has a controller calling its sub-project (provider). So the controller depends on the provider.

The provider is using grpc to call another service. The provider knows the service it calls, but the controller doesn't. (I do this way to follow the basic design pattern of de-coupling).

Right now, the problem is: the service which the provider calls throws `iServiceException`. But only the controller knows how to handle the exception.

Method 1: Since we cannot just rethrow the `iServiceException` from the provider (Because the controller doesn't know `iServiceException` and cannot catch it), we can just rethrow the standard java `Exception`, then the controller can catch it. But my concern here is: is this a good way to do? Since `Exception` contains less information than `iServiceException`.

Method 2: Implement another `ProviderException` then the controller catch it and handle the exception.

Which method is better? By the way, this microservice uses Spring framework, not sure if there is a better way to do this in Spring.

Comment: It's unclear from this question what the structure of this project is.  It sounds like your controller is calling an internal service which then calls a remote service over grpc.  If the controller knows how to handle the exception thrown by the rpc, why not just let the exception bubble up to the controller through the stack?  Perhaps add a little code to illustrate how this is structured.

Comment: @lane.maxwell My understanding is that the service is throwing the `iServiceException`, but the project containing the controller does not have a dependency on the library/API which defines `iServiceException`, and therefore the controller cannot do something like `try { } catch (iServiceException ex) { }` because it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Slaw yes, your understanding is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can propose to declare `@ControllerAdvice\@RestControllerAdvice` and handle `Exception.class` in your controller service. When the exception in provider will be thrown, your controller will show pretty response body with your exception.

But, it is always a good practice to handle proper exceptions and not just abstractions.